# Range of multiple list

Tags: python-3.x, list, range

I am learning Python with Kaggle and to try to understand one of the exercises, I am trying in VS Code to improve my comprehension of `list` and `range`.

I arrive to do so when checking only if one list is present in multiple lists :

```
#trying to get the results for each list keyword present in the lists string
for (a) in range(number_doc): 
    result = all(item in string[a] for item in keyword)
    print(result)`

>>> False
>>> False
>>> False
```

what I'd like to get is the correspondance for each keyword. I can do it individually by adding the index :

```
`result = all(item in string[a] for item in keyword **[0]**)`
#'casino' :
>>> True
>>> False
>>> False
`result = all(item in string[a] for item in keyword **[1]**)`
#'they' : 
>>> False
>>> True
>>> False
```

but I'd like to be able to do something as below (not sure if it is possible) :

```
`for (a,b) in range(number_doc,number_keyword): 
    result = all(item in string **[a]** for item in keyword **[b]**)
    print(result)`
`#'casino' :
>>> True
>>> False
>>> False
#'they' : 
>>> False
>>> True
>>> False`
```

```
keyword = ['casino']
#print(keyword)
string =['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?']
#print (string)
string_append = []

print ("The original keyword list is: " + str(keyword))
print ("The original string list is: " + str(string))

# Lower the characterof the list string (+ create list in list) and keyword
string = [item.lower().split() for item in string]
keyword = [item.lower() for item in keyword]

#print ("The transformed list string is: " + str(string_lower))
#string = [item.split () for item in string_lower]
print(keyword)

#get the range of the list string
number_doc = len(string)
print('number of doc : ' + str(number_doc))

#test the list string with the range number_doc 
for i in range(number_doc) : 
    print (string[i])

#print(string)
#keyword_lower in string
#result = any(item in string_lower[0] for item in keyword_lower)
#print(result)

#check if the list keyword is present in the lists string
for i in range(number_doc) : 
    result = any(item in string[i] for item in keyword)
    print(result)

#add 'they' to the list Keywords
keyword.append('they')
print (keyword)

#check if the list keyword is present in the lists string
for i in range(number_doc) : 
    result = any(item in string[i] for item in keyword)
    print(result)

#create a list by word in Keyword
# keyword = [item.lower().split() for item in keyword]
print (keyword)

#get the range of the list keyword
number_keyword = len(keyword)
print('number of keyword : ' + str(number_keyword))

#test the list keyword with the range number_keyword 
for i in range(number_keyword) : 
    print (keyword[i])

#trying to get the results for each list keyword present in the lists string
for (a) in range(number_doc): 
    result = all(item in string[a] for item in keyword)
    print(result)
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

I have been looking on the internet on how to get results based on crossing multiple lists